# Browser performance statistic service

Tags: javascript, performance, browser, web-statistics

I would like to create some html page with recomendation to update old wersion of browser or to install other browser (something like [this](http://www.sophrosynelife.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/example.png)).

I think it would be usefull for user to see performance (speed) comparision of browsers (like [this](http://support.threetags.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/browser_speed_test.PNG)), it helps him to make a choice.

Is there any service from which i can extract raw data about moder browser performance and to show it in such page.

For example i get (in any way - ajax maybe) such data:

```
{
    browsers: [
        ie: {
            edgeVersion: 10,
            generalizedSpeed: 8
        },
        chrome: {
            edgeVersion: 25,
            generalizedSpeed: 9999
        },
        firefox: {
            edgeVersion: 17,
            generalizedSpeed: 500
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

So i always have actual information and show it to user, i don't need to update image with browser comparision each time new browser version appears.

Comment: What do you mean by "speed"? HTML render speed? SunSpider/V8/Kraken JS benchmarks? Startup speed?

Comment: @tjameson, i mean abstract "generalized" browser speed (i know it is nonsense). User not need to know about 'html render and so on'. I want  to diplay simple visual bars (maybe it will be a little biased information).

Answer (score 0):

I have found this [online](https://opendata.socrata.com/Business/Browser-Speed/e3fb-j9c6). I am quite confident that other such resources are available, however what you will find, is that measuring performance and defining the correct metrics will be more problematic than gathering the data itself from a service. My reasoning behind saying this, is that browser performance is paradoxically a complex and simple subject.

On one hand, analysing the speed of rendering the DOM tree, repaints and reflows is dependent on the web application that you are using, not necessarily the browser.

On the other hand, you could simply analyse how long a browser takes to render a certain page (even these results can be subjective to some extent) Different rendering engines may perform slightly better than others at given tasks, however it does not mean that they are better rendering engines.

I suggest the following resources.

1. https://vimeo.com/103108124
2. https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/

In addition, there is some browser support for the `window.performance` object, which can be used to extract some findings about the performance of an application in a browser. If you compare the data from this object in different applications, you will be able to obtain some insight, but the problem of it being in a service is unresolved.